# K8 cronjob vs deployment spec for python app

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod, kubernetes-cronjob

I have a docker image with a few python functions that I would like to execute using a K8 cronjob.

I added the docker image to the cronjob spec so the functions would be executed on a schedule.

Would it be necessary or beneficial if I created a container with the same docker image via a deployment spec that would follow the logs?

Answer (score 2):

Depends on if you'd like to be able to use the logs for live debugging or not.

Every Job in Kubernetes creates a Pod, so essentially you can just look at the logs with:

```sh
kubectl logs <pod-name>
```

Another alternative is to stream your Pod logs to a logging tool like an [EFK](https://medium.com/@prasenjitsarkar_79320/part-7-deploying-efk-elasticsearch-fluentd-kibana-stack-on-oke-f7b6122492f) or [ELK](https://github.com/elastic/helm-charts) stack. Also, there are also many paid vendors that allow you send logs to the cloud, so that's another option.